# Remove lines not matching the required format in a csv file

Tags: awk, sed

I have a large amount of auto-generated CSV files that look like this:

```
1603145914502,48.12,0.085,s
1603145914815,48.12,0.020,s
1603145914941,48.12,0.019,s
1603145915404,48.12,0.031,s
1603145915612,48.12,0.033,s
1603145915899,48.12,0.019,s
```

one integer, two floats and a letter.

some of the files are corrupted due to a threading issue when they were generated:

```
1603145914502,48.12,0.085,s
1603145914815,48.12,0.020,s
1603145914941,48.12,0.019,s
1603145915404,48.12,0.031,s
1603145915612,48.12,0.033,s
1603145915899,48.12,0.019,s
1603145914502,48.12,0.085,s915899,48.12,0.019,s
1603145914815,48.12,0.020,s
1603145914941,48.12,0.019,s
1603145915404,48.12,0.031,s
1603145915612,48.12,0.033,s
1603145915899,48.12,0.019,s
1459143
1603145914815,48.12,0.020,s
1603145914941,48.12,0.019,s
1603145915404,48.12,0.031,s
```

Is there a way to find and remove lines that do not fit the format? it looks like something that awk could do really well, but I have absolutely no clue how to use it :)

If there is a way to do it, I would really appreciate if the command could be explained as well so I can learn something from it.

---

Edit: I'm clarifying the format:

INT,FLOAT,FLOAT,CHAR

There is never a space after the comma. The values can be anything that fit the format above.

Comment: It might be possible that a line was broken but it still follows the format.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details about what "lines that do not fit the format" means. Lines that have more than the expected number of columns? Lines that don't have `s` in the 4th column? etc.

Comment: @Bodo, I've clarified the format; so you can see that only 2 lines in the example do not fit it.

Comment: So, could things like `-12,Inf,-1e-20,,` which match that format occur in the input?

Comment: No because the data is financial so it has specific ranges; the left column is a ms timestamp, then price, volume and one char for direction. Numbers will always be positive as well. So the floats will always be xxx.yyy type

Comment: one quick question: I understand that regex are a good fit for this and I see that all the answers proposed are perl / grep regular expressions. Is my assumption that awk would be a good fit wrong?

Comment: awk would be fine but the natural solution in awk would still be a regexp that matches the line. I added that and sed equivalent to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aeither of these  should be all you need to match simple/basic formats (e.g. no signs, no exponents) of `INT,FLOAT,FLOAT,CHAR`:

```
grep -E '^[0-9]+,([0-9]+\.[0-9]+,){2}[[:alpha:]]$' file

sed -En '/^[0-9]+,([0-9]+\.[0-9]+,){2}[[:alpha:]]$/p' file

awk '/^[0-9]+,([0-9]+\.[0-9]+,){2}[[:alpha:]]$/' file
```

Comment: (assuming the INTs are positive (looks like a unix time with miliseconds so should be fine), and the FLOAT as well and there's no `1.2e-6`, `NaN`, `Inf`, and CHAR is meant to be a letter).

Answer (score 2):

> **Is there a way to find and remove lines that do not fit the format?**

Many ways, here's one:

```
$ perl -n -i.bak -e 'print if /\d{13},\d\d.\d\d,\d\.\d\d\d,s$/' t.dat

$ diff t.dat.bak t.dat
7d6
< 1603145914502,48.12,0.085,s915899,48.12,0.019,s
13d11
< 1459143

$ cat t.dat
1603145914502,48.12,0.085,s
1603145914815,48.12,0.020,s
1603145914941,48.12,0.019,s
1603145915404,48.12,0.031,s
1603145915612,48.12,0.033,s
1603145915899,48.12,0.019,s
1603145914815,48.12,0.020,s
1603145914941,48.12,0.019,s
1603145915404,48.12,0.031,s
1603145915612,48.12,0.033,s
1603145915899,48.12,0.019,s
1603145914815,48.12,0.020,s
1603145914941,48.12,0.019,s
1603145915404,48.12,0.031,s
$
```

I tend to reach for perl before awk/sed but the same operation is doable using awk in much the same way

---

> **I would really appreciate if the command could be explained as well so I can learn something from it.**

Explanation

- `-n` loop over lines from file but do not print them to STDOUT
- `-i` do an in-place edit to the file
- `-i.bak` and keep a backup copy with specified filename extension in case I make a mistake!
- `-e 'script'` run commands in script (on each line of input since -n option)
- `print if ...` print the line if it matches the conditional expression
- `/ ... /` - use this *regular expression* for pattern-matching
- `^` at the start of a line ...
- `\d` match a digit
- `{3}` match exactly three of the previously specified character
- `,` match a literal comma character
- `\.` match a literal stop character (otherwise `.` is a wildcard metacharacter)
- `s` match a literal s character
- `$` match end of line (i.e. there must be no further characters on the line.

A more flexible expression would be `^\d+,\d+.\d+,\d+.\d+,[a-zA-Z]$

- `+` at least one of the previous character
- `[...]` one of this specified set
- `[a-z]` any lowercase ASCII character between a and z inclusive
- `[[:alpha:]]` any character in the POSIX alphabetic set
- `\p{Lowercase_Letter}` any Unicode character with the *lowercase letter* property

Perl regular expressions are a little different from regular expressions used in awk/grep. I think modern versions of awk/grep have options to use perl style regular expressions. See man page for grep's `-P` option

Answer (score 1):

```
# expect
#          1         2
# 123456789012345678901234567
# 160314591xxxx,48.12,0.0xx,s

grep -Ex '160314591[0-9]{4},48\.12,0\.0[0-9]{2},s' < file.csv
```

Would do a strict matching. You can make more or less strict as to what exactly you want it to match by adjusting that regular expression.